# How to unit test 'navigate' with Query Params in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This is my method in the component.

```
 editThis(id) {
    this.router.navigate(['/categories/edit'], { queryParams: { id: id } });
  }
```

This is my unit test-case.

```
fit('should call navigate with correct params', () => {
    component.editThis("5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0");
    expect(new MockRouter().navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/categories/edit'], { queryParams: { id: "5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0" } });
  });
```

This is the mocked router.

```
class MockRouter {
  navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
  navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');

}
```

I am getting this error.

> Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ '/categories/edit'
>   ], Object({ queryParams: Object({ id: '5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0' }) })
>   ] but it was never called.

Can you suggest me a way to test the method?

Full test code.

```
import { FacadeService } from './../../../services/facade.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CategoriesViewComponent } from './categories-view.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

var allCategories = [

  {
    "_id": "5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0",
    "name": "Politics",
    "updatedAt": "2019-03-04T17:26:54.262Z",
    "createdAt": "2019-03-04T17:26:54.262Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
];

class MockRouter {
  navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
  navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');

}

class MockedFacadeService {
  getUserDataFromLocalStorage() {
    return false;
  }
  getGuestPermissionsFromLocalStorage() {
    return { "comments": { "create": false, "read": true, "update": false, "deleteAny": false, "delete": false }, "post": { "create": false, "read": true, "update": false, "delete": false, "like": false, "dislike": false }, "category": { "create": false, "read": true, "update": false, "delete": false } };
  }
  getCategories() {
    return of(allCategories);
  }
}

describe('CategoriesViewComponent', () => {
  let component: CategoriesViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CategoriesViewComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AngularFontAwesomeModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [CategoriesViewComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: FacadeService, useClass: MockedFacadeService },
      { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoriesViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should call navigate with correct params', () => {
    component.editThis("5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0");
    expect(new MockRouter().navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/categories/edit'], { queryParams: { id: "5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0" } });
  });

});
```

Comment: Could you provide the full test configuration?

Comment: There is no way that your code under test could possibly call a method on the **new** object `new MockRouter()` that you create in the test. It calls this method on a **different** object. You need to inject a mock router in the component under test, then run your code, then test that the injected mock router has been called. Or you need to get a reference to the actual router used by the component, spy on it, run the code, and then verify that the spied methods have been called.

Comment: Of course that expect will always fail, you are instantiating a new mock router on it...

Comment: see https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/

Comment: Uploaded the whole test file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your line:

```
expect(new MockRouter().navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/categories/edit'], { queryParams: { id: "5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0" } });
```

to the following:

```
expect(TestBed.get(Router).navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/categories/edit'], { queryParams: { id: "5c7d5fde213e25232864dbe0" } });
```

This will get the actual router object that was instantiated in the TestBed.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The router already has a mock that you may use.

https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule